# In yii how to i use audit trail in log in/sign in?

Tags: yii, audit-trail

I'm developing now a yii application.
I've already use audit trail for logging my model regarding add, edit, delete. But how i can log the login/signin portion into my database using audit trail?

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass CWebUSer and extend afterLogin() method. You can follow this [tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/80/add-information-to-yii-app-user-by-extending-cwebuser-better-version/)

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#afterLogin-detail

```
This method is called after the user is successfully logged in. 
You may override this method to do some postprocessing 
(e.g. log the user login IP and time; load the user permission information).
```